# Type definition for an existing JavaScript library that resides in the global scope

Tags: typescript

I have to write some type definitions for an existing JavaScript library that resides in the global scope:

```
window.ThridPartyLibrary = {};
```

The d.ts definition would be something like this:

```
declare module ThridPartyLibrary 
{
    var foo: any;
    ...
}
```

or like this (depending on the 'shape' of the library):

```
declare var ThridPartyLibrary : IThridPartyLibrary 
interface IThridPartyLibrary 
{
    foo: any;
    ...
}
```

In both cases, however, it is not possible to make the Type of the library itself available so that for example I could pass it to a function:

```
declare function bar( library: ThirdPartyLibrary ): void;
```

In such a simple case on could pass the interface from the 2nd (interface) approach instead:

```
declare function bar( library: IThirdPartyLibrary ): void;
```

Problem is that the interface approach will not work since I have other stuff like nested sub modules and enums I want to describe:

```
declare module ThridPartyLibrary 
{
    var foo: any;
    module EvenMoreStuff
    {
        var bar: any;        
    }
    enum Things
    {
        Thing1 = 0,
        Thing2 = 1,
    }
}
```

So is there any other way to describe this library? The reason why I'm doing this is that I want to inject the library to an AngularJS function as a service and I'd like to provide the type information in the function signature.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [mixing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#declaration-merging), like this:

```
// The interface (or declare class)
interface ThirdPartyLibrary  
{
    // with properties and methods
    foo: any;
}

// The module with sub modules, enums, ...
declare module ThirdPartyLibrary  
{
    module EvenMoreStuff
    {
        var bar: any;        
    }
    enum Things
    {
        Thing1 = 0,
        Thing2 = 1,
    }
}

// now you can use the interface module mix as type for param
declare function bar(library: ThirdPartyLibrary): void;

function bar2(library: ThirdPartyLibrary, thing: ThirdPartyLibrary.Things) { 
    alert(thing+library.foo);
}

bar2({ foo: ":)" }, 0);
```

Works in the Playground ([Sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%2F%2F%20The%20interface%20%28or%20declare%20class%29%0Ainterface%20ThirdPartyLibrary%20%20%0A%7B%0A%09%2F%2F%20with%20properties%20and%20methods%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20The%20module%20with%20sub%20modules%2C%20enums%2C%20...%0Adeclare%20module%20ThirdPartyLibrary%20%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20module%20EvenMoreStuff%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20bar%3A%20any%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20enum%20Things%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Thing1%20%3D%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Thing2%20%3D%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20now%20you%20can%20use%20the%20interface%20module%20mix%20as%20type%20for%20param%0Adeclare%20function%20bar%28library%3A%20ThirdPartyLibrary%29%3A%20void%3B%0A%0Afunction%20bar2%28library%3A%20ThirdPartyLibrary%2C%20thing%3A%20ThirdPartyLibrary.Things%29%20%7B%20%0A%09alert%28thing%2Blibrary.foo%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Abar2%28%7B%20foo%3A%20%22%3A%29%22%20%7D%2C%200%29%3B%0A))

Answer (score 0):

Query the module for its type using the `typeof` operator

`declare function bar( library: typeof ThirdPartyLibrary ): void;`